# Compare script where files are on a different machine

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, path

I have a compare script where it will work when I put the files in the same directory as the script.
But what do I do when the compare files are on a different machine.  How do I setup the path with the ip address of where the files are located so I can run the python script from where I have my scripts stored.  This way I don't need to move the files to where I have the scripts stored or two a directory on the machine where the scripts are stored.  Hopefully this makes sense.
Scripts have a local address 192.168.1.100 (Linux Machine). and the files are on a Windows machine with 192.168.1.108

Comment: Automate the Process. Use FTP in windows and transfer the script in remote and then by using remote ssh execute the script.

Comment: The files will change each time we get a beta build we run the new tests then do a compare of the old tests so for now I prefer to run it manually